# Specrun - don't stop executing tests after a certain number fail

Tags: specflow

I am using specrun in visual studio to run my specflow unit tests.  I have found that after a certain number of tests fail, specrun will stop and skip any remaining tests.

How can I run all tests regardless of failures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding stopAfterFailures="-1" to the Execution node in default.srprofile:

```
<Execution retryFor="None" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" stopAfterFailures="-1" />
```